# Programmatically adding constraints eliminates window resizing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a subview I created programmatically. It's basically for handling selections when necessary and passing up the responder chain otherwise. So naturally I want it to fill the whole window, at any resize. So I added an array of constraints:

```
-(void)configureConstraintsForSubview:(NSView *)subview{
NSArray *constraints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: //Creates constraints
                        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0],
                        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0],
                        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0],
                        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0],
                        nil];
[self addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

However, instead of letting me resize the view along with the window, I can't resize the window at all! (The zoom button doesn't even do anything!) The console says something about being unable to mutually satisfy my constraints, and it attempts to recover by breaking one, but obviously that doesn't work. A few notes about my code: self is a PDFView subclass that was set in Interface Builder, subview is the parameter/argument representing the subview I want to constrain. I've never done constraints programmatically before, so I figure like I'm probably making some obvious error.

UPDATE: Here's the relevant portion of the error:

```
2014-03-25 15:40:31.345 <MyAppName>[3097:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6100000991e0 h=--& v=--& V:[EGLInteractionView:0x6100001fe100]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':EGLPDFView:0x60800014de10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000974d0 V:[EGLInteractionView:0x6100001fe100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':EGLPDFView:0x60800014de10 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000974d0 V:[EGLInteractionView:0x6100001fe100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':EGLPDFView:0x60800014de10 )>
```

Note that the class name EGLPDFView corresponds with self in the first snippet, and the class EGLInteractionView corresponds with subview in the first snippet.

Comment: Include the console message. Most likely, one or more views should have the setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = no set on them. The PDFView perhaps? Won't know until we see the console log.

Comment: Got it, I'll upload that after school today. I originally excluded it because it was pretty long. (Due to having a bunch of memory addresses in the error)

Comment: Probably, just a part of it will be enough

Comment: The issue here as seen in error is that, Default auto-resizing mask is conflicting with the autolayout constraint that you have set. Set "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO" on "EGLInteractionView".

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Yes, that worked. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.